# What's a procedure to solve this equation?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

$$ \sqrt{x} + \sqrt{x - 20} = 10 $$

Is there a procedure other than guess and check that can be used to solve this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [General Principles of Solving Radical Equations](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1793591/general-principles-of-solving-radical-equations). Or [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1350897), [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3114511), [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1457251), etc.

Comment: We may notice that l.h.s. is a strictly increasing function of $x$. Hence there are no roots or there is only one root. We may notice that $x=36$ is a root, hence the answer is $36$.

Comment: I don't understand the answer in the general principles of solving radical equations but when I get more time I'll look more into it